# Issue with Ordering Excel Rows by particular column programatically in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

I am trying to order 7 rows in descending order of data from a particular column.
The data in the excel spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Name---Actual----Budget---Budget%
Name1--$2000-----$5000--------40%
Name2--$5000-----$4000-------110%
```

etc....

I want to order the rows by the 'Budget%' column in descending order.

The Code I have so far is:

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet

objExcel.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
objExcel.Visible = False

objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\LLG\template.xlsx")
objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'CODE HERE PLACES DATA INTO CELLS ON SPREADSHEET

objSheet.Rows.Sort(column(4))
```

I left out the code that places the data into the cells since it is functioning fine, just the objsheet.rows.sort(column(4)) is completely wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

well you will probably need a second argument to the sort specifying descending

xlDescending

also I think you need to specify the range that the sort is to be applied to, something like

```
Set objRange = objsheet.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objExcel.Range("D1")

objRange.Sort objRange2, xlDescending
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried the method you suggested, but I still cant seem to get it to function. Is there something I have missed?